# In Javascript - setting an onclick attribute for a button that calls a function with a given argument

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm making a card game in Javascript and one of the things the webpage does is create buttons with the name of a card that you click to use the card. At least, in theory.

Code:

```
function addButton(card) {
    var newbutton = document.createElement("input");

    newbutton.setAttribute("type", button);
    newbutton.setAttribute("id", 'someButton');
    newbutton.setAttribute("value",card.displayName);
    newbutton.setAttribute("name",card.name);
    newbutton.setAttribute("onclick",'useCard(name)'); ///this is what's not working
```

What I'd like is for the onclick attribute to use the named card (the card's name is card.name, which might be different from its displayed name). Instead, it's using useCard with 'name' as the argument, which is obviously wrong. What's the correct line of code here?

Comment: Use a template. What you have is a lot of unneeded crap-code.

Comment: `button` and `name` are variables from an outer scope?

Answer (score 3):

Adding an event listener would be a better and cleaner option:

```
newbutton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  useCard(this.getAttribute("name"));
});
```

If you really need to support IE < 9, you have to check for `addEventListener` compatibility first and use `attachEvent` in case the former isn't supported:

```
// generic helper function
function addEventListenerX(elem, evt, listener) {
  if ("addEventListener" in window) {
    elem.addEventListener(evt, listener);
  }
  else {
    elem.attachEvent("on" + evt, listener);
  }
}


addEventListenerX(newbutton, 'click', function () {
  useCard(this.getAttribute("name"));
});
```

If you're already using a JS framework like jQuery or prototype, use their listener system. They will automatically add compatibliity for you.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I've added a patch ;)

Comment: Better: On page load: `var on = 'addEventListener' in window ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent';`. Then, when binding event handlers: `newbutton[on]('click', useCardListener);`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That won't work because `attachEvent` requires events to be prefixed with 'on'. I've added a helper function, now.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
newbutton.setAttribute("onclick",'useCard(name)'); ///this is what's not working
```

with this:

```
if (newbutton.addEventListener) {
    newbutton.addEventListener('click', function() { useCard( card.name ); });
else {
    newbutton.attachEvent('onclick', function() { useCard( card.name ); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 newbutton.setAttribute("onclick",'useCard("' + card.name + '")');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 newbutton.setAttribute("onclick",'useCard('+card.name+')');
```

in place of

```
 newbutton.setAttribute("onclick",'useCard(name)');
```